# SQL server Pivot Table issue

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a table with columns and values like:

```
Records Status       CustName      Amount

71      Blocked      Customer_1    132171
11      Booked       Customer_1    19974
3       Cancelled    Customer_1     3900
```

I want to write a query to get the data as :

```
CustName   Blocked_Recs    Blocked_amount  Booked_Recs  Booked_amount Cancelled_Recs Cancelled_amount
Customer_1  71              132171         11           19974          3              3900
```

The problem pertains to `SQL server 2008 R2`

What should be query exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do this:

```
 Select r1.c, 
        r1.[Blocked], 
        r2.[Blocked],
        r1.[Booked],
        r2.[Booked],
        r1.[Cancelled],
        r2.[Cancelled]

 from(select * from (select r, c, s from t) t
 pivot(max(r) for s in([Blocked],[Booked],[Cancelled]))p) r1

 join

 (select * from (select a, c, s from t) t
 pivot(max(a) for s in([Blocked],[Booked],[Cancelled]))p) r2 on r1.c = r2.c
```

Here is fiddle  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/acf78